# Significance of the series $q_1+{q_1}^2+{q_2}^3+{q_1}^4+{q_2}^5+{q_3}^6+{q_1}^7+\dots$, where ${q_1}=q^{1+\frac{4}{n}} (0<q<1).$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series
$$q_1+{q_1}^2+{q_2}^3+{q_1}^4+{q_2}^5+{q_3}^6+{q_1}^7+\dots,$$ where ${q_1}=q^{1+\frac{4}{n}} (0<q<1),$

is convergent (proved below). Does anyone know why people study a series like that? Is it related to bionomial triangle or something similar?

*Proof:*

The series equals
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=n-1}^{\infty} (q^{1+\frac{4}{n}})^{\frac{k(k+1))}{2}+n}\\
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{k+1} q^{m+4}q^{(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{m})(k(k+1))} 
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{k+1} \lambda_{k,m}\eta_k,
$$
where $\eta_k =q^{k+1+4}q^{(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{k+1})(k(k+1))}= q^{3k+5+\frac{k(k+1))}{2}}$,
and $\lambda_{k,m}=\frac{q^{m+4}q^{(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{m})(k(k+1))}}{\eta_k} =q^{(k+1-m)(\frac{2k}{m}-1)}$.

For $(k+1-m)(\frac{2k}{m}-1)\geq k+1-m$, (note when k=0, it equals 0=k+1-m, where m is definitely 1), $\sum_{m=1}^{k+1}\lambda_{k,m}\leq \sum_{m=1}^{k+1}q^{(k+1-m)}\leq \frac{1}{1-q}$. Besides, $\eta_k\leq q^{3k}$.

Therefore
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{k+1} \lambda_{k,m}\eta_k 
\leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{q^{3k}}{1-q},$$
which converges.

*A note for myself:* In searching for the proof, I tried to let q be 1/2, and suspected the power of q in each item is a natural number, guessing there might be a proof from that (like we can change the series to $q^{n_1}+q^{n_2}+\dots$), but it turns out not to be, e.g. ${q_3}^{13}=q^{30+1/3}$; I then find the series (each row and the sequence of sums of each row) is comparable to $\sum \frac{1}{2^n}$.

I guess there is perhaps a proof that, despite the power of q in an item being not always a natural number, one can still compare each item in the series to an item in  $\sum \frac{1}{2^n}$, though not in the same order; and then with the theorem that deranged absolutely convergent series has the same limit, we can prove it and the proof would be more elegant.

PS: is there any other way to prove it? In particular, is there a way to transform the series to double series and then use different ways of summing double series to prove that?

Comment: Note that $q_k\leq q$ since $0<q<1$. Thus the series in question is majorized by the (convergent) geometric series $\sum_{i=1}^\infty q^i$.

Comment: I see. That's quick.

Comment: Maybe I can further my above calculation to see what the limit is.